# Show there do not exist closed orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am considering the $2$D system
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}x(x-1)\sin \phi\\
\dot{\phi} &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[1-\cos \phi - \frac{1}{8} x\cos \phi],
\end{align}
where $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $-\pi \leq \phi \leq \pi$. I wish to show there exist no closed orbits. For visualisation, the phase portrait on a cylinder appears below, with a saddle point on $x = 0$ and stable and unstable fixed nodes at $x = 1$. Though it appears to be visually true, I am unsure as to how to produce a more formal argument demonstrating that it is true.

[image]

Comment: Is the second ODE correct?

Comment: @Gonçalo I have forgotten an $x$ factor.